# use of underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for a parameter

Tags: swift

According to the current Swift Book (Apple), “If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for that parameter.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2).” Apple Books. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-2/id881256329?mt=11

I would very much like to know why this would ever be done. It seems to me that a parameter either has an argument label (which must be used when calling the function) or it just has an argument name. I cannot imagine a use case for this.

```
func someFunction(_ firstParameterName: Int, secondParameterName: 
Int) {
// In the function body, firstParameterName and 
secondParameterName
// refer to the argument values for the first and second 
parameters.
}
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2).” Apple Books. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-2/id881256329?mt=11

Followup:
It hadn't really hit me yet that by default, all function invocations use what python would call keyword parameters. I get it now. It's funny, some of the things I thought were odd about javascript appear in Swift as well.

Comment: It's for when you want to call your functions like in good ol' `C`. `foo("bar")` instead of `foo(longBarParameterLabel: "bar")`.

Comment: One common use case is when the name of the parameter is already part of the function name, e.g. `setValue(_ value: Int)` or when the name has no meaning whatsoever e.g. `print(_ arguments: String...)`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can only do it for the first parameter. Rest of the parameters, if any, obviously would need a name. Also you can tag other parameters in same fashion. Try `someFunction(_ firstParameterName: Int, second ParameterName: Int)` and see what happens. Notice `second ParameterName` is with a space in between.

Comment: @Desdenova, you can do it with **any** parameter, not *only first*.

Comment: @Desdenova That's untrue.

Comment: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#argument-labels has guidelines when to use or to omit (explicit) argument labels.

Comment: 1/2 Think in terms of readable code that is concise. Would you rather call 'setFoo(bar:)` or setFoo()` with bar in it? Or for a more realistic example: which is more readable - not just to you, but others needing to understand your code - `add(a:b:)` or `add(_,_,)` which the source is actually the difference between `add(a:a:,b:b)` versus `add(a,b)`....

Comment: 2/2 BOTH are syntactically correct, take the same amount of memory/processing space (I think), and therefore work just as well. But why would you want to force your peers (coders) to say `add(a:a, b:b)`? Back in the day when Objective-C ruled the Apple universe everything was wordy and/or detailed. Swift introduced things that means you *can* do the latter example. (I don't know how long you've been coding Swift but we're nearing version 5.0 in around 5 years. Most languages fo not update that fast.)